# How can I get value of the button id from jquery ui dialog when user click?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui, click, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to create a jQuery UI dialog dynamically. Number of buttons in dialog depend on my JSON data. I need the button id when user click on it.

```
var deviceInfo = {
    "devices": [{ "deviceID": "11", "devicename": "test12" },
                { "deviceID": "12", "devicename": "test12" }]
};

for (var x in deviceInfo["devices"]) {
    arrButtons.push({
        text: "DeviceID:" + deviceInfo["devices"][x]["deviceID"], 
              id: deviceInfo["devices"][x]["deviceID"], click: function () {
            currentDeviceID = deviceInfo["devices"][x]["deviceID"];
            console.log("selected id:", currentDeviceID);
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    });
}

showDeviceID = function (dID) {
    console.log("deviceID", dID);
}

$("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    dialogClass: 'no-close',
    show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
    },
    buttons: arrButtons
});
```

Every time I get last id. Would you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `event` properties of the `click` handler.

```
$('button').click(function(e)
{
   e.target.id; // gives you the id of the button clicked.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @DinoMyte for your great help. now it's working, I get the button id which on user click. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
for (var x in deviceInfo["devices"]) {

    arrButtons.push({
        text: "DeviceID:" + deviceInfo["devices"][x]["deviceID"], id: deviceInfo["devices"][x]["deviceID"], click: function () {
            currentDeviceID = deviceInfo["devices"][x]["deviceID"];

            console.log("selected id:", currentDeviceID);

            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    });

}
```

For:

```
for (var x in deviceInfo["devices"]) {
    var device = deviceInfo["devices"][x]["deviceID"];

    arrButtons.push({
        device: {
            click: function () {
                console.log("selected id:", device);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Leo for your comment. Actually I need which button user click. Every button has id and I put it with my device id because I need which device user choose to show.

Comment: Thanks @Leo for your reply. I used your update version but it's show an error like: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"